# SQLite: How do I update values from another?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How do I update values from another table where the value of the column is 2010?

This is the select SQL statement that returns the results I want

```
SELECT Devices.Name,TempKaspersky.Lisence
FROM TempKaspersky
INNER JOIN devices
On lower(TempKaspersky.MachineName)=devices.name
Where TempKaspersky.Lisence=2010
```

Now i want to update Devices.lisence column with 2010? How can i achieve this in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
UPDATE Devices 
    SET Devices.lisence = 2010 
    WHERE Devices.Name IN 
        (SELECT lower(MachineName) FROM TempKaspersky WHERE Lisence=2010)
```

Comment: **@Erik Nedwidek**, the query you provided is invalid and would error out.